# Specifying different font (features) for section headings in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, fontspec, titlesec

I love old style figures. But I think old style figures don't look too good in section heading numbers (1, 1.1, 2 etc.). I'd like to see lining figures in section headings and proportional figures in text.

This minimal .tex file already works but might not be optimal:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setmainfont{Garamond-Pro.ttf}[Numbers = {OldStyle}]
\newfontfamily\foo{Garamond-Pro-Bold.ttf}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\foo} % Can I do this without specifyin \Large?
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\foo} % Can I do this without defining this for all section levels?

\begin{document}
\section{These are lining figures 123456}
These are old style figures: 123456.
\subsection{These are lining figures 123567}
These are old style figures: 123456.

\end{document}
```

**Q1**: Can I achieve the same without the need to specify the section heading sizes (`\Large` etc.). Now I'm just guessing the correct sizes and they might be wrong and makes the setup needlessly verbose.

**Q2**: Can I achieve the same in one go without the need to specify the font separately for each section level? Again, makes it too verbose.

**Bonus Q3**: Is my aesthetic thinking incorrect: should I instead use old style figures also in section headings if I use them elsewhere? I guess this is highly subjective, though.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `\addfontfeatures{Numbers=Lining}`?

Comment: @Ingmar, not sure how that would help me, could you elaborate? Setting the actual feature to the font is not the problem. The problem is I want to have a different font for section headings without manually doing that every time I create a section. I can do that, but I'd like to do it in a more general way. 

Doesn't `\addfontfeatures` just change the features "temporarily" and I need to manually revert the effect by issuing the command later again.  I want to define the fonts once and be done with it. I edited my example for it to be clearer.

Comment: I think you've basically answered your own questions. Yes, you do need to specify the size and weight for each section level (since that's how `titlesec` works). The `titlesec` documentation gives the values for the standard classes in its last appendix, so you don't need to guess.

Comment: @AlanMunn, thanks for the tip, now I see the defaults are there, great! But ok, with `titlesec`package I guess this is The Way.

Comment: You'd use `\addfontfeatures` with `\titleformat`, would be my suggetion. No need to define a `\newfontfamily`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @Ingmar. Will check that out also.

Comment: @Ingmar Using `\addfontfeatures` doesn't eliminate the need to respecify the size and weight using `titlesec`, and using a new font family specifically for the headings is conceptually more elegant (although that's clearly a subjective choice.)